# Next / Previous Post Links from Same Category and Alphabetically ordered

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

*RESOLVED*

I'm exhaustively searching for a method to provide **Next and Previous Post Links** in a different way from which it usually appears in **Single Post**.

**By DEFAULT it:**

- Is chronological ordered
- Links to posts from all blog categories

**But I NEED it:**

- ALPHABETICALLY ordered
- Linking to posts from SAME CATEGORY only

I'm not a developer but I found two codes and I think if I could merge both the problem would be solved. Could someone help me please?

**CODE 1** - Turn Next/Prev links alphabetcally, but not from same category ([source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166932/how-to-get-next-and-previous-post-links-alphabetically-by-title-across-post-ty))

```
function filter_next_post_sort($sort) {
    $sort = "ORDER BY p.post_title ASC LIMIT 1";
    return $sort;
}
function filter_next_post_where($where) {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_title > '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->post_title);
}

function filter_previous_post_sort($sort) {
    $sort = "ORDER BY p.post_title DESC LIMIT 1";
    return $sort;
}
function filter_previous_post_where($where) {
    global $post, $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_title < '%s' AND p.post_type = '". get_post_type($post)."' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->post_title);
}

add_filter('get_next_post_sort',   'filter_next_post_sort');
add_filter('get_next_post_where',  'filter_next_post_where');

add_filter('get_previous_post_sort',  'filter_previous_post_sort');
add_filter('get_previous_post_where', 'filter_previous_post_where');
```

**CODE 2** - Turn Next/Prev links from same category, but not alphabetically ([source](http://presscustomizr.com/snippet/restrict-post-navigation-category/))

```
add_filter( 'get_next_post_join', 'navigate_in_same_taxonomy_join', 20);
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_join', 'navigate_in_same_taxonomy_join', 20 );
function navigate_in_same_taxonomy_join() {
 global $wpdb;
 return " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id";
}


add_filter( 'get_next_post_where' , 'navigate_in_same_taxonomy_where' );
add_filter( 'get_previous_post_where' , 'navigate_in_same_taxonomy_where' );
function navigate_in_same_taxonomy_where( $original ) {
 global $wpdb, $post;
 $where = '';
 $taxonomy   = 'category';
 $op = ('get_previous_post_where' == current_filter()) ? '<' : '>';
 $where = $wpdb->prepare( "AND tt.taxonomy = %s", $taxonomy );
 if ( ! is_object_in_taxonomy( $post->post_type, $taxonomy ) )
 return $original ;

 $term_array = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

 $term_array = array_map( 'intval', $term_array );

 if ( ! $term_array || is_wp_error( $term_array ) )
 return $original ;

 $where = " AND tt.term_id IN (" . implode( ',', $term_array ) . ")";
 return $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE p.post_date $op %s AND p.post_type = %s AND p.post_status = 'publish' $where", $post->post_date, $post->post_type );
}
```

After weeks of searching for a solution, here is the [**FINAL ANSWER**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204265/next-previous-posts-links-alphabetically-and-from-same-category/)!

**THANK YOU FOR HELP ME!**

Comment: Unfortunately the code no longer works in latest WP and WooCommerce, at least for some products it leads to page not loading. I struggle to understand what changed in WP.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `get_adjacent_post();` this is provide you next or previous post.

This is for previous post:

```
<?php 
    $prev_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'taxonomy_slug' ); ?>
    if ( is_a( $prev_post, 'WP_Post' ) ) {
?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $prev_post->ID ); ?></a>

<?php } ?>
```

This is for next post:

```
<?php 
    $next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false, 'taxonomy_slug' );
    if ( is_a( $next_post, 'WP_Post' ) ) {
?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $next_post->ID ); ?></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Guys I'm glad about your responses, but this way the Next/Prev links don't work alphabetically. I found new info I guess can help me but I'm not a developer, so I don't know what to do.

I'm updating my question with new info. Please, read if you can.
Thanks again!